# Authentication error when using Git Bash to connect to Google Cloud (gcloud)

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I want to use gcloud in Git Bash to copy files over to my VM instance using the following command:

```
gcloud.cmd compute scp --recurse app/ root@[Instance_name]:/var/www/test --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a --project [project_name]
```

which results in:

```
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

I looked at the var/log/auth.log and the corresponding error is:

```
session opened for user root by david(uid=0)
```

I used gcloud auth login to authenticate myself, which redirected me to standard Google login webpage and I authenticated myself with my user. Looks like that does not have enough rights. How can I resolve the issue so I can authenticate properly and copy files

Comment: probably (!) not `root@[instance-name]` just `[instance-name]` so that you are authenticated on the instance as the currently logged-in user (not `root`).

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons, most of the OS images do not allow direct "root" user login (ssh/scp). The configuration file "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" can be configured/changed to allow root login over SSH. For example, [here is the example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/v2v_guide/preparation_before_the_p2v_migration-enable_root_login_over_ssh) to enable root login over SSh on Red Hat Linux. However, it is a compromise with the security.

As @DazWilkin pointed out in the comment you can authenticate on the instance using the currently logged-in user. It should work. The SSH keys will authenticate the user access.

Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp), for more information. You can [create SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) and add to the instance metadata or project metadata depending upon your requirement and can run the command with the parameter "--ssh-key-file" in the '[gcloud compute scp](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)' command. This should be good to authenticate with the provided SSH keys.